# Controller Set Identification Error in MoveIt [/move_group]

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, 
I'm trying to control a Stäubli TX-40 robot (CS8C controller) with MoveIt/RViz. 
It's possible to launch RViz with `roslaunch tx40_moveit_config moveit_planning_execution.launch sim:=false robot_ip:=<xxx>`. 
Also the robot's initial pose is displayed correctly. 
But after I plan and execute a new pose I get the following error messages:

```
[ERROR] [1622803303.326637667] [/move_group] [ros.moveit_ros_planning.trajectory_execution_manager]: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: [ joint_1 joint_2 joint_3 joint_4 joint_5 joint_6 ]
[ERROR] [1622803303.328418500] [/move_group] [ros.moveit_ros_planning.trajectory_execution_manager]: Known controllers and their joints:
[ERROR] [1622803303.328487897] [/move_group] [ros.moveit_ros_planning.plan_execution]: Apparently trajectory initialization failed
```

I'm using ROS melodic on a Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS x64 machine. 
I followed this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_MoveIt_Pkg_for_an_Industrial_Robot). 
This is my moveit_planning_execution.launch:

```
<launch>
    
      <!-- The planning and execution components of MoveIt! configured to run -->
      <!-- using the ROS-Industrial interface. -->
     
      <!-- Non-standard joint names:
           - Create a file [robot_moveit_config]/config/joint_names.yaml
               controller_joint_names: [joint_1, joint_2, ... joint_N] 
           - Update with joint names for your robot (in order expected by rbt controller)
           - and uncomment the following line: -->
      <!-- The following line is not necessary -->
      <!-- <rosparam command="load" file="$(find tx40_moveit_config)/config/joint_names.yaml"/> -->
      <!--   <rosparam command="load" file="$(find staubli_tx40_support)/config/joint_names_tx40.yaml"/> -->
     
      <!-- the "sim" argument controls whether we connect to a Simulated or Real robot -->
      <!--  - if sim=false, a robot_ip argument is required -->
      <arg name="sim" default="true" />
      <arg name="robot_ip" unless="$(arg sim)" />
     
      <!-- load the robot_description parameter before launching ROS-I nodes -->
      <include file="$(find tx40_moveit_config)/launch/planning_context.launch" >
        <arg name="load_robot_description" value="true" />
      </include>
    
      <!-- run the robot simulator and action interface nodes -->
      <group if="$(arg sim)">
        <include file="$(find industrial_robot_simulator)/launch/robot_interface_simulator.launch" />
      </group>
    
      <!-- run the "real robot" interface nodes -->
      <!--   - this typically includes: robot_state, motion_interface, and joint_trajectory_action nodes -->
      <!--   - replace these calls with appropriate robot-specific calls or launch files -->
      <group unless="$(arg sim)">
        <include file="$(find staubli_val3_driver)/launch/robot_interface_streaming.launch" >
          <arg name="robot_ip" value="$(arg robot_ip)"/>
        </include>
      </group>
    
      <!-- publish the robot state (tf transforms) -->
      <node name="staubli_tx40_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />
    
      <include file="$(find tx40_moveit_config)/launch/move_group.launch">
        <arg name="publish_monitored_planning_scene" value="true" />
      </include>
    
    <!--   <include file="$(find tx40_moveit_config)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch"> -->
    <!--     <arg name="config" value="true"/> -->
    <!--   </include> -->
    
      <include file="$(find tx40_moveit_config)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch">
        <arg name="rviz_config" value="$(find tx40_moveit_config)/launch/moveit.rviz"/>
      </include>
      
       <!-- <include file="$(find tx60l_moveit_config)/launch/default_warehouse_db.launch" /> -->
    
    </launch>
```

This is my controllers.yaml:

```
controller_list:
  - name: tx40_controller
    action_ns: joint_trajectory_action
    default: True
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints: 
      - joint_1
      - joint_2 
      - joint_3 
      - joint_4
      - joint_5
      - joint_6
```

This is my ros_controllers.yaml:

```
# Simulation settings for using moveit_sim_controllers
moveit_sim_hw_interface:
  joint_model_group: manipulator
  joint_model_group_pose: all-zeros
# Settings for ros_control_boilerplate control loop
generic_hw_control_loop:
  loop_hz: 300
  cycle_time_error_threshold: 0.01
# Settings for ros_control hardware interface
hardware_interface:
  joints:
    - joint_1
    - joint_2
    - joint_3
    - joint_4
    - joint_5
    - joint_6
  sim_control_mode: 1  # 0: position, 1: velocity
# Publish all joint states
# Creates the /joint_states topic necessary in ROS
joint_state_controller:
  type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
  publish_rate: 50
controller_list:
  []
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379580/%5B/move_group%5D-%5Bros.moveit_ros_planning.trajectory_execution_manager%5D:-unable-to-identify-any-set-of-controllers-that-can-actuate-the-specified-joints:-%5B-joint_1-joint_2-joint_3-joint_4-joint_5-joint_6-%5D/) by [jabra](https://answers.ros.org/users/75567/jabra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-06-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-04**:
Could you check whether #q379403 deals with this?

Key point: check the action server is connected.

**Comment by [jabra](https://answers.ros.org/users/75567/jabra/) on 2021-06-04**:
Thanks for your quick reply.
How do I check if the action server is connected?
I tried `rostopic list | grep -i goal` and `rostopic info /joint_trajectory_action/goal` from [link](https://answers.ros.org/question/301196/moveit-error-action-client-not-connected/).
These commands produced the following outputs:

```
/execute_trajectory/goal
/joint_trajectory_action/goal
/move_group/goal
/pickup/goal
/place/goal
```

and

```
Type: control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal

Publishers: None

Subscribers: 
 * /joint_trajectory_action (<my PC>)
```

Therefore, I filled the action_ns in my controllers.yaml with joint_trajectory_action.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-04**:\

> How do I check if the action server is connected?

by looking at the output of MoveIt. Like in #q379403, if it's not connected, MoveIt will complain with:

```
[ WARN] [1622623640.277582609]: Waiting for arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory to come up
```

and then finally:

```
[ERROR] [1622623652.277927833]: Action client not connected: arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
[ INFO] [1622623652.287814525]: Returned 0 controllers in list
```

the fact though that `Publishers: None` is shown for the `FollowJointTrajectory` server probably indicates that it's indeed not connected.

> Therefore, I filled the action_ns in my controllers.yaml with joint_trajectory_action.

please see my answer to #q379403. Your `controllers.yaml` is likely incorrect.

**Comment by [jabra](https://answers.ros.org/users/75567/jabra/) on 2021-06-04**:
As far as I understand the problem in #q379403 was that the `FollowJointTrajectory` server is expected at `<controller name>/follow_joint_trajectory`. But the driver starts the server at `/follow_joint_trajectory`. Therefore, I now leave the name value in my `controllers.yaml` empty. Unfortunately, that didn't help. Regarding the warning and error messages that the action server is not connected: I don't have these messages. But before I start planing in RViz I get:

```
[ WARN] [1622815253.629201409] [/robot_state] [ros.industrial_utils]: Unable to find user-specified joint names in 'controller_joint_names'
[ WARN] [1622815253.639934450] [/motion_streaming_interface] [ros.industrial_utils]: Unable to find user-specified joint names in 'controller_joint_names'
```

**Comment by [jabra](https://answers.ros.org/users/75567/jabra/) on 2021-06-04**:
And:

```
[ WARN] [1622815253.651804291] [/joint_trajectory_action] [ros.industrial_utils]: Unable to find user-specified joint names in 'controller_joint_names'
[ WARN] [1622815253.672325640] [/motion_streaming_interface] [ros.simple_message]: Tried to connect when socket already in connected state
[ WARN] [1622815254.670602137] [/joint_trajectory_action] [ros.industrial_robot_client.joint_trajectory_action]: Trajectory state not received for 1.000000 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assumed you already had updated the `tx40_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml` to load your `controllers.yaml` (this name is a guess, I'm referring to whatever name that file has in your case).

If you haven't, `controllers.yaml` is not loaded. The OP in #q379403 has merged it with `ros_controllers.yaml`, and that is already loaded by default.

Also:

```
<!--   <rosparam command="load" file="$(find staubli_tx40_support)/config/joint_names_tx40.yaml"/> -->
```

why did you comment this?

It's likely the cause of the `Unable to find user-specified joint names in 'controller_joint_names'` you show.

---

Edit:

> So now I merged my controllers.yaml with my ros_controllers.yaml.

it's up to you, but I would not do that.

It will work, but all other information in `ros_controllers.yaml` is specific to `ros_control`. The `staubli_val3_driver` is not `ros_control` based. To me it seems strange to mix everything into that file then.

> I tried that also many times before but I think I didn't leave the name value empty.

Another option would be to remap the topic on the side of the driver. You should then be able to use the `name` and `action_ns` you had earlier.

> So it was the same problem as in #q379403.

well, not quite: the OP there had already configured MoveIt to create the action client. He just had a minor configuration issue.

You didn't load the `controllers.yaml` file, causing MoveIt to not even create the client.

> By the way: I commented `<!--   <rosparam command="load" file="$(find staubli_tx40_support)/config/joint_names_tx40.yaml"/> -->` in my moveit_planning_execution.launch because I don't have a joint_names.yaml-file.

you really should create that file, even if the names are the default ones.

There's no guarantee they will stay the default ones, and this way you have a way to load them. The file is also part of the default set of files in a [robot support package](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/WorkingWithRosIndustrialRobotSupportPackages), and there are good reasons for those packages to contain a standard set of files.

> I used standard joint names.

newer versions of `industrial_robot_client` will not work if you don't configure the joint names. They will find missing parameters, report them and shut down.

Finally:

> I'm trying to control a Stäubli TX-40 robot (CS8C controller)

I believe you've had to create the robot support package yourself. Seeing as there is currently no TX40 support in [ros-industrial/staubli_experimental](https://github.com/ros-industrial/staubli_experimental): would you be willing to submit a pull request to add that support? It would be greatly appreciated.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jabra](https://answers.ros.org/users/75567/jabra/) on 2021-06-04**:
IT WORKS!!!
THANK YOU!!!
So now I merged my controllers.yaml with my ros_controllers.yaml.
I tried that also many times before but I think I didn't leave the name value empty.
So it was the same problem as in [#q379403](https://answers.ros.org/question/379403/how-to-use-staubli_val3_driver-industrial_robot_simulator-with-industrial_robot_client-and-moveit/).
By the way: I commented `<!--   <rosparam command="load" file="$(find staubli_tx40_support)/config/joint_names_tx40.yaml"/> -->` in my moveit_planning_execution.launch because I don't have a joint_names.yaml-file. I used standard joint names.
Again, thank you very much.

**Comment by [jabra](https://answers.ros.org/users/75567/jabra/) on 2021-06-07**:
Thank you for your helpful advice. I made the changes you recommended. Regarding the tx-40 support package: I didn't came up with the code myself. I found it [there](https://answers.ros.org/question/352137/velocity-overwriting-issue-when-physical-controller-is-connected/) and [there](https://github.com/Tomiliat/Staubli_backup/tree/master/staubli_ws/src/staubli_tx40_support) respectively.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-08**:
Looking at that package, *technically*, without written permission from the author, you cannot (re)use it for your own purposes. The `license` tag is set to `TODO`, which means it's currently unlicensed, which means *all rights reserved*.

There was already an issue about this [Tomiliat/Staubli_backup#1](https://github.com/Tomiliat/Staubli_backup/issues/1), in which the author stated "yes, it can be MIT", but he has not updated the files.